# 403 Error while trying to retrieve Reddit User's saved posts using JRAW

Tags: android, kotlin, http-status-code-403, reddit

I'm currently trying to get a users saved posts using the [JRAW reddit api wrapper](https://github.com/mattbdean/JRAW) using this code:

```
val helper = App.get().accountHelper
val paginator = helper.reddit.me()
                    .history("saved")
                    .build()

val saved = paginator.next()
```

[Context for App class](https://github.com/mattbdean/JRAW-Android/blob/08c7a3caee99ce81c37d6e5adcd8b608c3cbb702/example-app/src/main/java/net/dean/jraw/android/example/App.java)

Which always results in a 403 - Forbidden. I log in and get the oauth token by using [JRAW-Android new user example](https://github.com/mattbdean/JRAW-Android/blob/master/example-app/src/main/java/net/dean/jraw/android/example/UserOverviewActivity.java) then switch to the user `accountHelper.switchToUser(userName)` which shows the account is authenticated..

Any ideas why i'm not able to authenticate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't realize Reddit had [scopes](https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/scopes.json). I had to add the `history` scope to the strings array when requesting `getAuthorizationUrl`

```
String[] scopes = new String[]{ "read", "identity", "account", "save", "history"};
String authUrl = helper.getAuthorizationUrl(requestRefreshToken, useMobileSite, scopes);
```